# Redirecting Chrome users to canvas created images (that are over 2mb)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

I have a JavaScript application which creates relatively large canvas images, depending on the size of the webpage. For some pages, the size of the canvas `.toDataURL();` will surpass 2mb, and upon trying to direct the user to that image with `window.location` it will give an 
 "Oh snap" Chrome crash window immediately.

After doing some research I found that the max url size in Chrome is limited to  [2 * 1024 * 1024 bytes](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#hfE6470xZHk/chrome/common/chrome_constants.cc&q=kMaxURLChars&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc). It works fine in FF4, so presumably it has a higher limit.

Are there any other methods how to pass a `canvas` image onto a new page without any server interaction?

**Examples:** Canvas creation only works with FF4/newer versions of Chrome. Wait for the canvas to be overlayed on top of the page, shift-clicking it will call the url change with:

```
var a = canvas[0].toDataURL();
window.location.assign(a);
```

Give it a good few seconds to load the canvas (there is no message which indicates that the page has been overlayed with one)

Canvas >2mb: [example 1](http://hertzen.com/experiments/html2canvas/tests/arrangement/)

Canvas <2mb: [example 2](http://hertzen.com/experiments/html2canvas/tests/combination/), [example 3](http://hertzen.com/experiments/html2canvas/tests/palmtrees/)

Comment: Not the solution you're looking for, but can you just have the page be a single `<img>` tag instead of a dataurl?

Comment: @Jeff The ideal plan was to only have 1 page, which is the one with the HTML that gets the canvas overlayed on top of it. When the user is directed to the image, it wouldn't be an actual page (it isn't situated on the server or anything), but dynamically created page on the browser (like the canvas image created with toDataURL() as that image actually doesn't reside anywhere on the server, but is passed as a seperate "page"). Reading all that back, not sure if it made any sense... In short, I'd want the created canvas to be passed as a seperate tab/window, without having any code on the page.

Comment: No, that makes sense, I think.  If your main concern is having the page dynamically created, you could achieve the same functionality by doing `document.write("<img src='dataurl'></img>")`.  But if you're set on using the dataurl, I don't mean to steer your off course, just trying to offer another suggestion.

Comment: @Jeff That's almost perfect. The problem now is though that the new opened page isn't an image, but an html page containing an image. The difference is that browsers would display the image dimensions etc in the window title if it was an image instead of a page. Can the dynamically created page be a dynamic image, meaning the contents of the image are written from the page that initiated the window.open?

Comment: yes, the same way you did before, just set the img src to `canvas[0].toDataURL();`. Also, I'm using Chrome 12 on mac, and it's not displaying the image dimensions in the window title-- i think each browser will handle that type of thing differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own both pages, the one you are posting from and the one you are posting too, check out the postMessage API that allows you to pass data from one page to another.

Page A:

```
var w = window.open("pageB.html");
w.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // You can only post messages once they page has loaded.
  w.postMessage(imgDataURI, "*");
});
```

Page B:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(msg) {
  var data = msg.data;
  //data will be the string 
});
```

If you need to not have a page on the server URI encode an html page, with the above code in and open that - admittedly it is a hack.  Below is an example that displays test:

```
window.open("data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PGh0bWw%2BPGJvZHk%2BPGgxPlRlc3Q8L2gxPjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw%2BDQo%3D");
```

An example of the HTML that you would encode is at http://jsbin.com/akobi4, then from page A you would call `var w = window.open("data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw%2BDQo8aHRtbD4NCjxoZWFkPg0KPG1ldGEgY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCAvPg0KICA8c2NyaXB0Pg0KICAgIHdpbmRvdy5hZGRFdmVudExpc3RlbmVyKCJtZXNzYWdlIiwgZnVuY3Rpb24obXNnKSB7DQogICAgICB2YXIgaW1nMSA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCJpbWcxIik7DQogICAgICBpbWcxLnNyYyA9IG1zZy5kYXRhOw0KICAgIH0pOw0KICA8L3NjcmlwdD4NCiAgPC9oZWFkPg0KPGJvZHk%2BDQogIDxpbWcgaWQ9ImltZzEiIC8%2BDQo8L2JvZHk%2BDQo8L2h0bWw%2B");`

```
w.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // You can only post messages once they page has loaded.
  w.postMessage(imgDataURI, "*");
});
```

Comment: This solution would require Page B to actually be a real page though (i.e. a page situated on the server etc.)? Even if that was the case, would it be able to serve the new page as an image, instead of an HTML document containing the image?

Comment: This is for the part of your question that said "Are there any other methods how to pass a canvas image onto a new page without any server interaction?" - which indicated you could create a new page. ;)  but the answer is no, it would have to be an window with a page hosting the image.

Comment: @Kinlan Sorry, I had trouble describing exactly what I was after in my question, but ideally I wouldn't want to create a new page (on the server).

Comment: @Niklas - no problem :) ... I have just updated my answer a little.  You can use window.open to open a uri encoded html page which has the above code in.

Comment: @Kinlan That will unfortunately just come back to the initial problem, of the URL exceeding the 2mb won't it?

Comment: No, because you need to include the code that pulls the data in from the other page that has posted it.  So in essence this might be a couple of kilobytes worth of javascript.

Comment: @Kinlan Oh right, I see what you mean now. Does this method really have any advantage of just doing `var w = window.open();
                var canvasDom=w.document;
                canvasDom.write("<img src='"+canvas[0].toDataURL()+"'></img>");` as how I understood the messageAPI, it won't be able to make the page itself the image, but just load the image onto the page as an element?

Comment: @Kinlan It works to the extent that it provides a page with an image element. What I really would want though, is a page that *is* the image, as is the case if you just pass the URL the contents of the canvas.

Comment: @Kinlan Is it a bug though? It has a defined limitation in the chrome_constants.cc file, so unless that limitation is going to be increased, it is working as intended from Google's perspective. Think this is a duplicate of my problem http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69227. PS I really do appreciate your effort to help me on this issue though